# Pandas dropna() not removing entire row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

When I serached a way to remove an entire column in pandas if there is a null/NaN value, the only appropriate function I found was dropna(). For some reason, it's not removing the entire row as intended, but instead replacing the null values with zero. As I want to discard the entire row to then make a mean age of the animals from  the dataframe, I need a way to not count the NaN values.
Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = {'animal': ['cat', 'cat', 'snake', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'snake', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog'],
'age': [2.5, 3, 0.5, np.nan, 5, 2, 4.5, np.nan, 7, 3],
'visits': [1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1],
'priority': ['yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no']}

labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, labels)

df.dropna(inplace= True)
df.head()
```

In this case, I need to delete the Dog 'd' and Cat 'h'. But the code that comes out is:

[image: Output]

To note I have also done this, and it didn't work either:

```
df2 = df.dropna()
```

Comment: I don't reproduce it. Can you try `df.dropna(how='any')`? Which pandas version do you have?

Comment: Accoring to your ouput, it works fine. I see ne null's in the dataframe afterwards.

Comment: @GedasMiksenas, there are no `NaN` values, but the information on row `d` is one of the rows that should be removed. Just, the missing value has been set to zero.

Comment: @propelledaviator, have you looked at what the dataframe looks like just after you create it? I think it's possible something is converting the `NaN` values to 0 before you try to remove them, so `dropna()` isn't finding any.

Comment: The code you provided it working as it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to specify the axis = 1 and any to remove column
see :  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

```
df.dropna(axis=1, inplace= True, how='any')
```

if you want just delet the row :

```
df.dropna(inplace= True, how='any')
```

Comment: `any` is already the default parameter for `how`, also OP wants to remove rows, so`axis=1` is not correct

Comment: I put the example to show the different options of the dropna function

Comment: I think sI ran into a bug, I reran the program after closing it and now it's working, you really helped, thanks!